# Determine computational complexity of recursive algorithm

Tags: python, combinations, time-complexity

I am attempting to determine if an algorithm that I wrote operates in polynomial time and, at the moment I can't figure out how count to this function that it uses

```
def combo(list, size):
    if size == 0 or not list:                            # order doesn't matter
        return [list[:0]]                                # xyz == yzx
    else:
        result = []
        for i in range(0, (len(list) - size) + 1):       # iff enough left
            pick = list[i:i+1]
            rest = list[i+1:]                            # drop [:i] part
            for x in combo(rest, size - 1):
                result.append(pick + x)
        return result
```

Comment: Polynomial in what? The result is a list with `\binom{len(list)}{size}` elements, so the complexity can't be less than that (and if my envelope-less back-of-envelope calculations are right, that's the complexity you have). For fixed `size`, it's polynomial in `len(list)`. `combo(list, len(list)//2)` is `O(2^len(list)/sqrt(len(list)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an algorithm for "k-combinations": given n items, select k of them, treating ordering as irrelevant. From the ancients, we know how many combinations to expect:

```
    n!
-----------
(n - k)! k!
```

For a given n (for example, 10), that expression is maximized when k equals half of n (5). As either n or k approach the extremes, the number of combinations gets much smaller.

With a little bit of reorganizing and simplifying, we can rewrite your code so that the number of calls to `combos()` is roughly equal to the number of combinations in the worst case. Interestingly, the number of calls and the number of combinations have a nicely symmetrical inverse relationship.

Most important is that both are **bounded above by the formula shown above for the worst case**. That effectively is the `O()` bound that you're asking for. But maybe not exactly, because the rewritten code makes fewer subroutine calls than your code, even though they do produce the same results. The short-circuiting logic in the example below prevents the extra calls and thus allows the worst-case argument to operate cleanly.

If that formula is your worst-case bound, does your algorithm run in polynomial time? I'm more intuitive than expert on such matters, but I think the answer is no. The worst case is when `k = n / 2`, which gives you the following simplification. Even though the denominator gets really big really fast, it pales in comparison to the Chuck-Norris rate of growth of the numerator.

```
      n!
-------------
(n/2)! (n/2)!

# For example, when n = 40.

       product(1..40)             product(      21..40)   # Eat my dust, Homer!
-----------------------------  =  ---------------------
product(1..20) product(1..20)     product(1..20       )   # Doh!

# Q.E.D.
```

An empirical illustration for many values of n and k:

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import factorial

n_calls = 0

def combos(vals, size):
    # Track the number of calls.
    global n_calls
    n_calls += 1

    # Basically your algorithm, but simplified
    # and written as a generator.
    for i in range(0, len(vals) - size + 1):
        v = vals[i]
        if size == 1:
            yield [v]
        else:
            for c in combos(vals[i+1:], size - 1):
                yield [v] + c

def expected_n(n, k):
    # The mathematical formula for expected N of k-combinations.
    return factorial(n) / ( factorial(n - k) * factorial(k) )

def main():
    global n_calls

    # Run through a bunch of values for n and k.
    max_n = 15
    for n in range(1, max_n + 1):
        # Worst case is when k is half of n.
        worst_case = expected_n(n, n // 2)

        for k in range(1, n + 1):
            # Get the combos and count the calls.
            n_calls = 0
            vs = list(range(n))
            cs = list(combos(vs, k))

            # Our result agrees with:
            #   - itertools.combinations
            #   - the math
            #   - the worst-case analysis
            assert cs      == list(list(c) for c in combinations(vs, k))
            assert len(cs) == expected_n(n, k)
            assert n_calls <= worst_case
            assert len(cs) <= worst_case

            # Inspect the numbers for one value of n.
            if n == max_n:
                print [n, k, len(cs), n_calls]

main()
```

Output:

```
[15, 1, 15, 1]
[15, 2, 105, 15]
[15, 3, 455, 105]
[15, 4, 1365, 455]
[15, 5, 3003, 1365]
[15, 6, 5005, 3003]
[15, 7, 6435, 5005]
[15, 8, 6435, 6435]
[15, 9, 5005, 6435]
[15, 10, 3003, 5005]
[15, 11, 1365, 3003]
[15, 12, 455, 1365]
[15, 13, 105, 455]
[15, 14, 15, 105]
[15, 15, 1, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Run Snake Run profile viewer.  It takes a profile output and creates a nice visualization of the function calls.

You run your program with the cProfile module and then send the output log to Run Snake Run:

```
python -m cProfile -o profile.log your_program.py
runsnake profile.log
```

That example is for Linux; Windows usage probably varies slightly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your `size` variable.

If *n* is the length of your list list (shadowing here, btw).

For `size = 1`, you're looking at *n* calls to `combo`.

If we define a function f(*n*) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (*n*-1),

... for `size = 2`, you're looking at f(*n*) function calls.

If we define a function g(*n*) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(*n*-1),

... for `size = 3`, you're looking at g(*n*) function calls.

So it seems you could say that your function's complexity is bounded by ***O***(*n* ^ *s*), where *n* is the length of your list and *s* is your size parameter.

Comment: It may *return* fewer combos (I'm not sure), but the `combo` function is called as  often as I listed.